# External URL into a iframe to embed an external url within Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I would like to embed a pptx that is uploaded into a folder in OneDrive within a `iframe` tag in a Django template. I have the urls stored in a model and saved into the SQLite database. In this sense, in the *views.py* file, I have the following code:

```
context = {
  'selectedunit': selectedunit,
  'url_to_be_inserted': MyModel.objects.filter(unit=selectedunit)
}
return render(request, 'web.html', context)
```

The code for *web.html* is very easy:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container col-lg-8">
  <div class="center">
      <iframe class="center" src={{ url_to_be_inserted.url }} width="100%" height="300%" frameborder="0"/>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The result is the snapshot below:
[image]

While, I would like to embed the ppt into the web site. If I directly insert the URL, instead of using the context variable, it works. That is to say:

```
<iframe class="center" src="https://..." width="100%" height="300%" frameborder="0"/>
```

In this case, the result is as follows (ppt embedded into the Web site):
[image]

The reason why doing in this sense is because, depending on the **selectedunit** variable, I would like to address a different pptx with a different URL and I would like to dynamically change the pointer (as you see above by filtering the model).

How could I solve it?

Many thanks in advance